# What causes foreign key = nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Generator has_many results
Result belongs_to generator

When i run rails console : Result.find(1) , the generator_id= nil. Why is this so ??? When i'm creating the data , the routes are like this :
localhost:3000/generator/1/results/new

It has got no error with the following code. BUt how come when i have this in my Generator/index.html

```
<% generator.results.each do |result| %>
        <td><%= result.ncbi_ref_seq %></td>
        <td><%= result.genome_sample %></td>
        <td><%= result.binding_times %></td>
<%end%>
```

they're empty. Whereas the @generators.each do |generator| gives me the values of the generator. In other words, the result's value belonging to this generator is empty but the generator values are shown. What i want is to have all generators and their result value to be shown. Can some1 help me ?

## Generator.model

```
class Generator < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :results , :dependent => :destroy
  attr_accessible :choice, :primer_length, :random_primer_generated, :genome_sample, :generator_id
```

## GeneratorController.rb

```
def index
        @generators = Generator.all
      end

def create    
    @generator = Generator.new(generator_params)
    @generator.choice = params[:choice]
      if params[:choice] == 'Randomly'
          @generator.random_generate(generator_params)
      elsif params[:choice] == 'No_of_ATGC'
          @generator.no_ATGC(params[:no_A],params[:no_T],params[:no_G],params[:no_C])
      elsif params[:choice] == 'Seating'
          @generator.seating(params[:user_seq])
      end

    @generator.result_choice=params[:result_choice]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @generator.save
          if @generator.result_choice == 'Yes'
            format.html { redirect_to(new_generator_result_path(@generator)) }
          else
            format.html { redirect_to @generator, notice: 'Result was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @generator }
          end
      else 
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @generator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

## Result Model

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :ncbi_ref_seq,:genome_seq, :genome_sample
   belongs_to :generator, foreign_key: "generator_id"
```

## ResultController

```
def index
    @results = Result.all
  end
def create
    @result = Result.new(result_params)
    @result.generate_result(result_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @result.save
        format.html { redirect_to @result, notice: 'Result was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @result }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @result.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

## schema.rb

```
create_table "generators", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "primer_length"
    t.integer  "no_A"
    t.integer  "no_T"
    t.integer  "no_G"
    t.integer  "no_C"
    t.string   "choice"
    t.string   "random_primer_generated"
    t.string   "user_seq"
    t.string   "c_primer"
    t.string   "result_choice"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "results", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "generator_id"
    t.string   "ncbi_ref_seq"
    t.string   "genome_seq"
    t.string   "genome_sample"
    t.integer  "binding_times"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "results", ["generator_id"], name: "index_results_on_generator_id"

  create_table "results_{:column_options=>{:null=>true}}", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "result_id",                           null: false
    t.integer  "{:column_options=>{:null=>true}}_id", null: false
    t.integer  "generator_id"
    t.string   "ncbi_ref_seq"
    t.string   "genome_seq"
    t.string   "genome_sample"
    t.integer  "binding_times"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "results_{:column_options=>{:null=>true}}", ["generator_id"], name: "index_results_{:column_options=>{:null=>true}}_on_generator_id"
```

Comment: How is a result associated with the generator. What does the result form look like? Also could you link you models (at least the relations/validations)

Comment: Controllers are not needed here. Please add models (associations part) and important piece from `db/schema.rb`

Comment: Why did you add `foreign_key: "generator_id"`? This is not needed unless you want to alter default name

Comment: Hi michael well i include the foreign key: "generator_id" because i've been referring to many sources and i'm just following their steps but sadly i still can't get my desired output. Can u help me to check if the ResultController create function is correct ? i'm not really sure how to link the result with my generator... what i'm getting now is foreign key = nil

Comment: Remove `foreign_key: "generator_id"` and try again. + add log for the new & create request

Comment: And add code from controllers for `result_params` and `generator_params`

Comment: how do i add log for the new & create req ?

Comment: Can u show me what do u mean ? in terms of code please ?